# Setting hostname in IIS, include www?

Tags: iis, hostname

I want to set the hostname for a website I'm adding in IIS 7, however do I include the www in the hostname or not? because I want both www.mysite.com and mysite.com both to point to mysite on the server.

thanks!

Comment: Probably a serverfault.com question, but you will have to add both entries in the Bindings. Unfortunately IIS does not support wildcard subdomains that I am aware of.

Comment: I just realized IIS 7 lets me add more than 1 binding to the website, so I added one for www and one without. is this the correct method?

what about for ssl? our cert only works with www for some reason, is this because of the way we bought it?

Comment: Yea, it will only work with the domain name (including sub domain) that you bought it for.  And yes, you did your bindings correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set bindings for both the www and non-www variants, so both will be mapped to your site.

Note that, for SEO and Web Analytics reasons, it's usually a good idea to have only one variant (either www or not-www) used on your site. To make this work, you can set up an HTTP redirect (in IIS, in your code, or your hoster can probably enable it on their end) from all requests from one variant to your preferred variant.  If you have IIS or the hoster do the redirect, then you only need to bind your site to the preferred hostname.